# Strange text being added to my SVN commits.

Tags: svn, commit

Here's an example:

```
    private void btnUndo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
<<<<<<< .mine
=======
```

The third and fourth line are being added to other developers machines when they do an update with from my commit. I'm using SVN.

What is being added here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You/Somebody had a conflict on the update/commit and you didn't resolve it before checking in.

The `<<<<<` and `=====` is there to show you what part of the source code is conflicting, and you need to resolve those before you actually commit -- the commit may even have warned you about it, and you may have confirmed to SVN that it was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

That's saying that there is a conflict in the file with that line, and that this is *your local file* that is in conflict. There is likely a "theirs" portion nearby (above maybe?) that represents *the repository's code* that doesn't agree with yours.

Answer (score 0):

The other developer seems to be committing a file in conflict status.

`svn commit` doesn't allow you to commit conflicted file that are not resolved (you have to do an `svn resolved` first).

Perhaps a bigger question to ask is why/how he committed this file to the repository?